# Why the table is not created despite the Python script ran successfully in IDLE?

Tags: python-2.7, pymssql

Here is my script that ran successfully, but still i cannot see the table being created in SQL  Server's database.

```
import _mssql
conn = _mssql.connect(server='MAQSOOD-PC', user='sa', password='123', \
    database='TestDB')
conn.execute_non_query('CREATE TABLE persons(id INT, name VARCHAR(100))')
conn.execute_non_query("INSERT INTO persons VALUES(1, 'John Doe')")
conn.execute_non_query("INSERT INTO persons VALUES(2, 'Jane Doe')")
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Please confirm the version of the library you are using.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Maybe the library I am using is not correct. I have Windows 7, 64 bit intel platform. Can you recommend my which library i should use?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you need to commit the transaction.

Try this version instead:

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect('MAQSOOD-PC', 'sa', '123', 'tempdb')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE persons(id INT, name VARCHAR(100))')
cur.commit()

cur.execute("INSERT INTO persons VALUES (1, 'John Doe')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO persons VALUES (2, 'Jane Doe')")
cur.commit()

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM persons')

for row in cur:
   print(row)
```

Comment: Still facing the same issue. The table is not there even after refreshing DB in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: There are no errors from Python? What of the log on the server?

Comment: From where I can check the log?